# How to use orderby with JCo in java

Tags: java, jco

I am new to SAP software and JCo, so pardon my novice mistakes.

I want to use orderby clause with JCo java library but did not find any hint about that on internet.

1. This code fetches table names, but I want to fetch data by order.
2. Second thing is if just want to get rows count, then how can I get that?

Code:

```
        JCoDestination client = (JCoDestination) sapconnector.getBaseConnection();
        JCoRepository repo = client.getRepository();
        JCoFunctionTemplate ftemplate = repo.getFunctionTemplate(dataSource.getRfcName());
        JCoFunction function = ftemplate.getFunction();
        JCoParameterList input = function.getImportParameterList();
        input.setValue(QUERY_TABLE, "DD02L");
        
        JCoParameterList output = function.getExportParameterList();
    
        JCoTable fieldsTable = 
        function.getTableParameterList().getTable("FIELDS");
        fieldsTable.setRow(0);
        fieldsTable.setValue("FIELDNAME", "TABNAME");
        // ???? sort TABNAME ASC|DESC
        function.execute(client);
    
        System.out.println("result:" + output.toXML());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the naming convention you used, like "`QUERY_TABLE`", I assume you are using `RFC_READ_TABLE` which is probably implied by "`getRfcName()`". In this case, there is no `ORDER BY`. If you need `ORDER BY`, you will have to write your own custom RFC function module.

To your second question, to get record count of table, use function `EM_GET_NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES`, then:

`JCoTable inputTable = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("IT_TABLES");
inputTable.appendRow();
inputTable.setValue("TABNAME", "<table_name>");`

Comment: If i use EM_GET_NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES as rfc name and get function template the import parameter list and export parameter list get null, so how to use it? any documentation or source link?

Comment: You have to import the parameter IT_TABLES as table, and put the first field "TABNAME" as your table name. Then, the result is in the field "TABROWS". The main thing here is to set value to the table parameter. See my updated answer.